# Retrieve data being parsed by SAXParser on runtime

Tags: java, saxparser

I have this method which parse xml data as InputStream

```
 public static void parseXml(InputStream stream, DefaultHandler handler)
{
    try
    {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        parser.parse(stream, handler);
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException pce)
    {
        // some code here
    }
    catch (SAXParseException spe)
    {
        // if exception is caught, log current data being parsed by SAXParser here
    }
    catch (SAXException se)
    { 
        // if exception is caught, log current data being parsed by SAXParser here
    }
    catch (IOException ie)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to log the data being parsed by SAXParser whenever an SAXParseException/SAXException is caught?

Comment: You can get the lineNumber and columnNumber and the message from SAXException . Is that what you need ?

Comment: Oh no. I was thinking of something like this:

`<root>
    <child>
        <grandchild>text 1</grandchild>
    </child>
    <child>
        <grandchild>text 2</grandchild>
    </child>
</root>`

If any part of the xml caught an error while parsing, per se <grandchild>text2</grandchild>, I could have that logged